# Как с помощью Javascript редактировать HTML код страницы?

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим, у нас есть страница, нам надо чтобы когда в консоли Javascript прописывается функция выполнялась такая штука. Javascript ищет часть кода страницы `(div class="class_web")` и изменяла его на `(div class="class_web2")` - все должно быть только на javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут проще использовать jquery

```
$('class_web').removeClass('class_web').addClass('class_web2');
```

Comment: А как в консоли Javascript тогда действовать?

Comment: если jquery подключен то пишешь то что я привел в примере

Comment: А в Google Chrome как его подключить?

Comment: Тебе надо  в html дописать вот такую строку 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

и jqury убдет подключен

Comment: А если у меня поиск запускается?

Comment: скажи как ты добавляешь эту строку. 
Через консоль это сделать нельзя, если что

Comment: event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. даже так

Comment: Извиняюсь, поставь перед именем класса в самом начале точку. Но только в самом начале

    $('.class_web').removeClass('class_web').addClass('class_web2');